# registration form php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a web page in which i display information about paintings.

I created a web page called "register.php" in which the user before placing an order of a painting has to fill a register form. Then a page called "details.php" appears asking for the user to input some more details. Finally a page called "vieworders.php" displays, showing details of the orderand the status of the painting.

Question 1: I have created a database called "users" which have the following fields "id(primary key auto increment),username,email and password. Why when the user submit the registration form, data are not showing up in my database??

Question 2: How the user will be able to come back any time and check the status of the painting??

Here is my code:

register.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$id = $_POST["accept"];
$paintingname = $_POST["accept1"];

$host = "xx";
$user = "xx";
$pass= "xx";
$dbname = "xx";
$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass, $dbname );

$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['paintingname'] = $paintingname;

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed : ".$conn->connect_error); //fixme
}

    if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {

        $username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]) : "";
        $email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]) : "";
        $password = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["password"]) : "";
        $password2 = isset($_POST["password2"]) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["password2"]) : "";


        if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
            array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
        }

        // first check the database to make sure
        // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
        $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $user_check_query);
        $user1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if ($user1) { // if user exists
            if ($user1['username'] === $username) {
                array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
            }

            if ($user1['email'] === $email) {
                array_push($errors, "email already exists");
            }
        }

        // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

            $query = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) 
                VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);

        }
    }

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration system PHP and MySQL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h2>Register</h2>
</div>

<form method="post" action="confirm.php">

    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" required />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_1" required />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Confirm password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_2" required />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user" >Register</button>
    </div>
    <p>
        Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

details.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table with database</title>
    <style type ="text/css">
        table {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background-colour: #FFC;
        }
        th {
            border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
        }
        td {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
$servername = "xx";
$username = "xx";
$password= "xx";
$dbname = "xx";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password, $dbname );


$id = $_POST["accept"];

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed : ".$conn->connect_error); //fixme
}
$sql=  "SELECT * FROM `listart` where id =".$id;
$result=$conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>\n";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Image</th>";
    echo "<th>Description</th>";
    echo "<th>Date of completion</th>";
    echo "<th>Painting Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Height</th>";
    echo "<th>Width</th>";
    echo "<th>Price</th>";

    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>"; echo ' <img src= "data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" height = "200 width = "200"/>'; echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["description"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["Dateofcompletion"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["pname"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["height"]." mm "."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["width"]." mm "."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>"."£ ".$row["price"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td><form action='register.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='accept' value='".$row["id"]."'/><input type='hidden' name='accept1' value='".$row["pname"]."'/> <input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='Order'><button type='button' onclick=\"history.back();\">Back</button></form></td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";

    }
    echo "</table>\n";
}

$conn->close();
?>


</body>
</html>
```

vieworders.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table with database</title>
    <style type ="text/css">
        table {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background-colour: #FFC;
        }
        th {
            border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
        }
        td {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
<h2>Here is a table with your orders!</h2>
<div>

<?php
session_start();
$servername = "xx";
$username = "xx";
$password= "xx";
$dbname = "xx";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password, $dbname );


$id =  $_SESSION['id'];
$paintingname =  $_SESSION['paintingname'];


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $uname = isset($_POST["uname"]) ? $conn -> real_escape_string($_POST["uname"]):"";
        $email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $conn -> real_escape_string($_POST["email"]):"";
        $paddress = isset($_POST["padd"]) ? $conn ->  real_escape_string($_POST["padd"]):"";
        $phonenumber = isset($_POST["phonenumber"]) ? $conn -> real_escape_string($_POST["phonenumber"]):"";
    }


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed : ".$conn->connect_error); //fixme
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO vieworders(id,paintingname,username,email,postalcode,phonenumber) VALUES
    ('$id','$paintingname','$uname','$email','$paddress','$phonenumber');";

//echo "<p><b>$sql</b></p>";

if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
    echo "<p> Insert successful </p>";
}
else {
    die("error on insert".$conn->error);
}


$sql  = "SELECT * FROM `vieworders`";
$result1=$conn->query($sql);


if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>\n";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Painting Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Username</th>";
    echo "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "<th>Postal code</th>";
    echo "<th>Phone number</th>";
    echo "<th>Order status</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["paintingname"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["username"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["email"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["postalcode"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["phonenumber"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["status"]."</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
}

$conn->close();

?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Now to the question, have you replaced the values of variables like `$servername = "xx";` etc. from **xx** to your actual database details? And for your other question about users returning to check orders, you'll need to build a login flow.

Comment: yes i replaced the values with xx ! i am 100% sure that my details are correct tho.. i will give a look what a login flow is ,thanks!

Comment: Is there any error returned upon submissionof /accessing `register.php`? if yes, please update the answer with the error.

Comment: there is not any error returned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're posting the registration form to `confirm.php`, so the code in `register.php` is never executed